# See What Redo/Undo Will Do on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

Hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> **Undoes** the last action, and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> **Re**does it.
In order to see *what exactly* you are about to Undo/Redo, you can click on "Edit" on the top of the screen.

**Question:**
What is the keyboard shortcut to find out *what exactly* you are about to Undo/Redo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut to see what Undo would do; if there is one I don't know about it.

The workaround I'd suggest would be <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> (focuses the menu bar), then <kbd>e</kbd> (selects the Edit menu) and then <kbd>↓</kbd> (opens the menu).

Comment: I don't think so. ctrl+f2 is defined as "Move focus to the menu bar", there seem to be no shortcut to jump to specific menus.